# how to handle linebreak <br> in react

Tags: json, reactjs, html

I am setting up an application and At GUI side, I would like to display the textcomment in different lines rather than in one single line. 
currently it works as follows:
1. From backend json file is received which has key:value pair for comment. 
Example->
Comment: "Application Entity Title for Service.
 The sending system must use exactly the same name to send data to service.

2. At GUI side, after parsing the JSON file, GUI tries to display the comment.

Issue: GUI is not recognizing the HTML tag
 and not displaying a line break.

Question: do I need to handle it in the backend(in C#) in a different way?

json received from backend:

```
Comment: "Application Entity Title for Service.<br/> The sending system must use exactly the same name to send data to service. <br/>"
```

GUI react code

```
<div className="Setting__Comment">
  <p>
    <strong>Description:&nbsp;</strong>
     {node.Comment}
  </p>
</div>
```

Current Result at GUI side

```
Description: Application Entity Title for Service.<br/> The sending system must use exactly the same name to send data to service. <br/>
```

Expected Results.

```
Description: Application Entity Title for Service. 
             The sending system must use exactly the same name to send data to 
             service.
```

Solution which worked for me:

```
  displayComment(){
    var node = this.props.treeNode;
    return {__html: node.Comment};

            <div className="SettingsTreeValueNode__Comment">
              <p>
                <strong>Description:&nbsp;</strong>
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.displayComment()}/>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: from where you are getting this `<br/>` means is it coming in the `node.Comment` or from somewhere else?

Comment: yes i am getting it from node.Comment. To be clear, getrequest is sent to server from client, and as a response from server, client gets the json object. and client goes through this json object and gets the information of "Comment" .

Comment: then you need to set the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property.
follow this link https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: thank you everyone.

Comment: <div className="SettingsTreeValueNode__Comment">
              <p>
                <strong>Description:&nbsp;</strong>
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.displayComment()}/>
              </p>
            </div>     displayComment(){
    var node = this.props.treeNode;
    return {__html: node.Comment};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better break down your text into render-able blocks. if you have a `<br>` in your message, then it should be handled separately as an html token, not a text.
so, i'd recommend return an array from your service and for br tokens just render a br explicitly.

Alternatively, you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render the content as is, but it's not the standard way and should be avoided as much as possible.

- for `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` just refer to react documentation here:
  https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: i shall give it a try now

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
    <div className="Setting__Comment">
     <p>
       <strong>Description:&nbsp;</strong>
       <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html: node.Comment} />
     </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: are your sure this will gonna work?

Comment: i tried this way, it didnt work, ERROR: Uncaught Invariant Violation: `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML` must be in the form `{__html: ...}`.

Comment: displayComment(){
    var node = this.props.treeNode;
    return {__html: node.Comment};               <div className="SettingsTreeValueNode__Comment">
              <p>
                <strong>Description:&nbsp;</strong>
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.displayComment()}/>
              </p>
            </div>

Comment: Yes <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={node.Comment} /> should be <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html: node.Comment} />. Please refer https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
<div className="Setting__Comment">
     <p>
       <strong>Description:&nbsp;</strong>
       <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html : node.Comment}} />
     </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `split('<br/>')` the string by `<br/>` and convert to `Array`.
Then, In React component, Iterate or use indexes to display array values:-

```js
class App extends React.Component{
 render(){
 var Comment = "Application Entity Title for Service.<br/> The sending system must use exactly the same    name to send data to service. <br/>";
  var array = Comment.split('<br/>');
  // console.log(array);
  return(
    <div>
    <div className="Setting__Comment">
         <p>
           <strong>Description:&nbsp;</strong>
            {array.map(comment => <React.Fragment>{comment}<br/></React.Fragment>)
            }
         </p>    
     </div>
    </div>  )
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```

Comment: What if i don't know how many <br/> is coming?

Comment: this is the only case for <br/> that you have handled.
What if in string you are getting <h1> or any other html element. Please try to put generic solutions.